# DAX - How do I use DATES in SWITCH statement

Tags: date, powerbi, switch-statement, dax

I am having a bit of tough time wrapping my head around this. I have a column based on response time in hours and our company's SLA (service level agreement) is that all incoming inquires should be answered within 2 days (the response time in hours is total hours spent on responding to inquiry).

The problem is that our company operates with winter time (7 h 45 min) and summer time (7 h). My dataset consist both and I want Power BI to differientiate winter and summer time when I try to compute SLA. In winter time 1 working day = 7 h 45 min and in summer time = 7 h. I have just used the average of summer/winter time = 7 h 30 min. The SLA column consist 3 data types, "Innen en arbeidsdag", "Innen to arbeidsdager" and "over 2 arbeidsdager".

My dataset is called 'Masterdata' and I have used this syntax so far:

```
    SLA = SWITCH(TRUE(),Masterdata[Svartid i t]>15,
     "Over to arbeidsdager", Masterdata[Svartid i t]>7.5, 
"Innen to arbeidsdager", Masterdata[Svartid i t]<=7.5, "Innen en arbeidsdag")
```

my columns 'Svartid i t' (response time) 'SLA' is so far ok and looks like this:

```
Svartid i t                SLA   
   6,12             Innen en arbeidsdag   
   11,73            Innen to arbeidsdager  
   20,42            Over to arbeidsdager   
    1,07            Innen en arbeidsdag    
    etc                    etc
```

But how can I use DATES in this syntax to tell Power BI that 'Svartid i t' (response time) YTD column from 15th May to 15th September is summer time, Working day = 7 h?

```
Summer time: 'Svartid i t' <= 7, "Innen en arbeidsdag", 'Svartid i t' > 7, "Innen to arbeidsdager", 'Svartid i t' > 14, "Over to arbeidsdager"
Winter time: 'Svartid i t' <= 7.75, "Innen en arbeidsdag", 'Svartid i t' > 7.75, "Innen to arbeidsdager", 'Svartid i t' > 15.5, "Over to arbeidsdager"
```

Comment: Don't post your company's business data on StackOverflow. Instead, create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This is indeed fictive data!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
VAR hours = 
    IF( (MONTH(MasterData[YTD]) >= 5 && DAY(MasterData[YTD]) >= 15)
        && (MONTH(MasterData[YTD]) <= 9 && DAY(MasterData[YTD]) <= 15),
        7, 7.45 )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        Masterdata[Svartid i t] > 2 * hours, "Over to arbeidsdager",
        Masterdata[Svartid i t] > hours, "Innen to arbeidsdager",
        Masterdata[Svartid i t] <= hours, "Innen en arbeidsdag"
    )
```

Make sure to put it in a *calculated column*. Your sample data is not suitable to verify the formula, so I changed it. But the result will look like this:

[image]